# Pickle weakref object

Tags: python, class, memory-management, pickle, weak-references

I have a dictionary called Eggs:

```py
Eggs = {}
```

I have a class called UserEgg:

```py
class UserEgg:
    def __init__(self, user):
        self.warns = 0
        self.xp = 0
        self.user = user
        self.mute_time = 0
        self.records = []

    def InfoEmb(self):
        self.InfoEmbed = discord.Embed(title=f"{self.user} | User-info")
        self.InfoEmbed.set_thumbnail(url=self.user.avatar_url)
        self.InfoEmbed.add_field(name="Buttons:",
                                 value="⚠️: Warn user\n: Mute user\n: Kick user\n: Ban user\n: Open records\n❌: Close")
        return self.InfoEmbed
```

The Egg dict is supposed to contain an id (string) and an UserEgg object:

```py
Eggs = {"122938192381923": UserEgg(0)}
```

I want to have a `save()` function to save this Egg dict to a file (preferably pickle)

This is what I have:

```py
def save(Eggs):
    with open("user_data.pkl", "wb") as fp:
        pickle.dump(Eggs, fp)
```

When I use the `save(Eggs)` function now I get `Cannot pickle weakref object`

Is there any way to make it a non-weakref object or fix the error?